# How to login any application through twitter account using php?

Tags: php, twitter

My question is, as all know if we open any application, there is a option for login through different accounts like face book,Google+,twitter. I want to write a code in PHP to login my application through twitter account details. Is that possible? how the application compares the information of user using two different account? And allow them to login? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for Twitter oAuth:

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/introduction

More specifically, their "application-only" authentication:

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only